# AWS Step functions State.Format not working with policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I have a step function task where I try to set an SQS queue policy based on dynamic values passed as input. Unfortunately, it completes whenever I execute the step, but the policy document it assigns to the Q is invalid, and "State.Format" does not work.

```
"SetQueueAttributes": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Parameters": {
    "Attributes": {
      "Policy": {
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "Allow-SNS-SendMessage",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource": "States.Format('arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{}:{}', $.Account, $.tenantId)",
            "Condition": {
              "ArnEquals": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "States.Format('arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:{}:my-execution-results', $.Account)"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "QueueUrl.$": "$.CreatQueueResult.QueueUrl"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:setQueueAttributes",
  "End": true
}
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself States.Format is just like JSON path selector so any policy key must end with .$ in order for States.Format to work properly